# convert data in csv format to xml like format using Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, csv

Need some help converting data in csv to xml format. I am new to python programming.

Source Data:
parent,child,component
Source1,Mapping,mp1
Source1,Mapping,mp2
Source2,Mapping,mp3
Source2,Mapping,mp4
Source2,Workflow,wf1
Source2,Workflow,wf2

```
Target: 
    <folder recursive="false" path="/Source1">
        <objectList type="Mapping">
            <object name="mp1"/>
            <object name="mp2/>
         </objectList>
    </folder>      
    <folder recursive="false" path="/Source2">
        <objectList type="Mapping">
            <object name="mp3"/>
            <object name="mp4"/>
        </objectList>
        <objectList type="Workflow">
            <object name="wf1"/>
            <object name="wf2"/>
        </objectList>
    </folder>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is a pretty interesting question, and it took some effort to get there. Most of it was actually done to get the data in the proper format; the actual xml creation was relatively easy.

I'll try to explain as we go along:

```
from lxml import etree
import copy

csv_string = """Source1,Mapping,mp1
Source1,Mapping,mp2
Source2,Mapping,mp3
Source2,Mapping,mp4
Source2,Workflow,wf1
Source2,Workflow,wf2"""

#first, get the data out of the csv string; we don't actually need the csv module for that
p_csv = [item.split(',') for item in csv_string.split('\n')]
#and from that, some relevant info:
n_sauces = set([pc[0] for pc in p_csv])
n_jobs = set([pc[1] for pc in p_csv])

#now the hardest part (for me) getting the info down to the right format for xml:
combos = []
for pc in p_csv:
    combo = []
    for sauce in n_sauces:        
        for job in n_jobs:            
            if pc[0]==sauce and pc[1]==job:
                combo.extend([sauce,job]) 
        combos.append(combo)

unique_combos = list(set(tuple(x) for x in combos))

final_list = []  
for sauce in sorted(list(n_sauces)):  
    jobs = [sauce]
    job=[]
    for uc in sorted(unique_combos):    
        if uc[0]==sauce:            
            job.append(uc[1])
    jobs.append(job)
    final_list.append(jobs)    

#with the final list, we can prepare the document: first, the template:
template = """<top>
    <folder recursive="false" path="xxx">
        <objectList type="yyy">
            <object name="zzz"/>            
         </objectList>
    </folder>    
</top>
"""
doc = etree.XML(template)

#then an empty final document
slate = """<top>    
</top>
"""
final_doc = etree.XML(slate)

#and to the composition: first, create data sources:
folder_source = doc.xpath('/top/folder')[0]
objectList_source = doc.xpath('//objectList')[0]
object_source = doc.xpath('//object')[0]
#then a destination for the new info:
dest = final_doc.xpath('/top')[0]
#and finally, crafting the new document:
for fl in final_list:
    new_fold = copy.copy(folder_source)
    new_fold.attrib['path']= fl[0]
    for f in fl[1]:       
        new_objectList = copy.copy(objectList_source)        
        new_objectList.attrib['type']=f        
        
        new_object = copy.copy(object_source)
        for pc in (p_csv):
            if pc[0]==fl[0] and pc[1]==f:
                new_object = copy.copy(object_source)
                new_object.attrib['name']=pc[2]

                #here we start a series of append()s:
                new_objectList.append(new_object)       
        new_fold.append(new_objectList)
    dest.append(new_fold)

#and the final clean up:
to_rem = ['xxx','yyy','zzz']
for tr in to_rem:
    rem_exp = f'//*[@*="{tr}"]'
    deletables = final_doc.xpath(rem_exp)
    for deletable in deletables:
        deletable.getparent().remove(deletable)
#bottom line:
print(etree.tostring(final_doc).decode())
```

Ouput:

```
<top>    
<folder recursive="false" path="Source1">
        <objectList type="Mapping">
            <object name="mp1"/>            
         <object name="mp2"/>            
         </objectList>
    </folder>    
<folder recursive="false" path="Source2">
        <objectList type="Mapping">
            <object name="mp3"/>            
         <object name="mp4"/>            
         </objectList>
    <objectList type="Workflow">
            <object name="wf1"/>            
         <object name="wf2"/>            
         </objectList>
    </folder>    
</top>
```